# WebStorm - quick find related scripts

Tags: javascript, node.js, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I'm working on a `nodejs` project. Is there any way in WebStorm v11 to make a "quick search" of the files that are requiring a script?

Let's say you got a tab on WebStorm and you are working on `script.js`. This file is being required (used) from `controller.js` and `main.js`, is there any easy way from the `script.js` tab to quick find the scripts that are requiring it?

What I currently do is <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + F</kbd> and type the script name, but it is getting annoying because sometimes you have a-very-long-and-descriptive-script-name.js and mostly because I don't like typing again and again when the computer should be able to perform this for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can right click the file in project tree and select *Find Usages* (Alt-F7) to find where a script was used. WebStorm does a decent job when figuring out where a script is used but it's not 100% perfect.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: A quicker way to do it (without the need to touch the mouse) would be to press Alt + Home (labelled "Jump to Navigation Bar" in the keymap if the keys are different) and then Alt + F7.